# TeamCity snapshot build configuration

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-10

I have big problem with configuring TC. It's 10.0.2 version.

I want build chain like this:
Main - Restore nuget and rebuild solution.
Code analysis - Analyse code result(do not checkout) use Main as dependency.
Publish - Publish to Azure - Use result of Main.

I set Main to:
Build numer format:`%build.counter%.%build.vcs.number....%`
VCS checkout dir: auto

Code analysis
Build number format:`%build.counter%.%dep.<mainId>%.%build.vcs.number...%`
VCS checkout dir:`%dep.<mainId>.build.default.checkoutDir%`

And the main dir is:    `55660246e9f668c3`
And Code Analysis searching in:    `9ccd5731845f5aba`

So it's wrong. Why?
Why?

## EDIT:

What I set VCS checkout directory in "Code Analysis" build configuration to hardcoded directiory name of "Main" e.x. to `55660246e9f668c3` then it work.

So the problem is with `%dep.<mainId>.build.default.checkoutDir%`

Comment: The build number formats should play no role here. The VCS root does play a role, but not the VCS checkout dir. Are you using the same VCS root in both Main & Analysis?

Comment: Yes, that same VCS root.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a snapshot dependency, that builds from the same chain. This will ensure that the same branch, from the same root, with the same revision number (point in time) is checked out to the directory. If you use an artifact dependency, in addition to the snapshot dependency, you can achieve the same point in time consistency. So after your step 1 build runs, regardless of what new changes exist, your second build will be working with the same files your first had.